# Magento 1.9 cannot make customer login, undefined offset + undefined variable

Tags: magento, ubuntu-16.04, magento-1.9, php-7, phpseclib

I have a really strange problem. Yesterday I was working with magento just fine and today when I opened the pc and tried login on my account after cleaning cache & session it gives me this error on customer login:

`Error occurred. Please try again later` on the frontend.

I dig into the system.log and I have this:

`ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 158 in {...}/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php on line 3426 and 3317
ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: cmsPageIdentifier in {...}/default/template/page/html/header.phtml on line 29`

and this is the code in question

Line 7-10:

`if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms')
{
    $cmsPageIdentifier = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();
}`

Line 29:

`<?php elseif ($cmsPageIdentifier && $cmsPageIdentifier == "conferma-invio") : ?>`

In sso.log I have this
`DEBUG (7): HTTP status: 503 when trying to get user authentication
DEBUG (7): Field Status was empty in webapi response`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually fixed the BigInteger and I remained only with the sso.log.

Dug into it and I found that there was another module error blocking customer login. Setting that module to `false` in `app/etc/modules/Module_Name.xml` fixed it.

Comment: added verification with isset()

Comment: Where? Line 3426 is blank in 2.0.10: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/2.0.10/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php#L3426 And that line in 1.0.10 doesn't do an array lookup: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/1.0.10/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php#L3426 I'm asking because if you found a legit bug I'd like to submit a pull request to phpseclib that fixes it. But I need to know where the fix was needed. Being able to reproduce it would also be good so a unit test could be written since idk if the pull request would be accepted without the unit test...

Comment: As is it seems possible that Magento is simply using an ancient version of phpseclib and that phpseclib, itself, fixed the issue years ago and Magento just never updated the copy of it that they include (assuming that they include a copy at all)

Comment: it depends on the magento version. I had 2 different issues with phpseclib in different magento versions. The issue is with the phpseclib included in magento.